# How do I fix syntax errors related to type hints when using an external library like GitPython?

Tags: python, gitpython

When trying to run a Python script I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from git.exc import *  # @NoMove @IgnorePep8
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\exc.py", line 10, in <module>
from git.compat import safe_decode
  File "C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\compat.py", line 36
is_win: bool = os.name == "nt"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

These errors seem to be related to GitPython. I successfully installed GitPython 3.1.37 and I am running Python 3.5.2.

Anyone familiar with these type of errors that would point me in right direction to fix these errors?

Comment: That version of `GitPython` is not compatible with that version of python. It has a [minimum Python version of `3.7`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython#requirements).

Comment: You’re running Python 3.5. [PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/) variable annotations (`is_win: bool`) is only available on Python 3.6 and above.